# failed to install bcrypt python

Tags: python, python-2.7, bcrypt

Python version 2.7

```
user 'jenkins': installation works
pip install bcrypt
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): bcrypt in /home/jenkins/.virtualenvs/dal/lib/python2.7/site-packages
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): cffi>=1.1 in /home/jenkins/.virtualenvs/dal/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from bcrypt)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): six>=1.4.1 in /home/jenkins/.virtualenvs/dal/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from bcrypt)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): pycparser in /home/jenkins/.virtualenvs/dal/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from cffi>=1.1->bcrypt)
```

under `root` user:

```
sudo su
root@server_name:/apps/app_name# pip install bcrypt
Collecting bcrypt
  Using cached bcrypt-2.0.0.tar.gz
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): cffi>=1.1 in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from bcrypt)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): six>=1.4.1 in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from bcrypt)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): pycparser in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from cffi>=1.1->bcrypt)
Installing collected packages: bcrypt
  Running setup.py install for bcrypt ... error
    Complete output from command /usr/bin/python -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-UQAoWx/bcrypt/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-BL_G1e-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile:
    <module 'pycparser' from '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pycparser/__init__.pyc'>
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/tmp/pip-build-UQAoWx/bcrypt/setup.py", line 226, in <module>
        **keywords_with_side_effects(sys.argv)
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/distutils/core.py", line 112, in setup
        _setup_distribution = dist = klass(attrs)
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/setuptools/dist.py", line 225, in __init__
        _Distribution.__init__(self,attrs)
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/distutils/dist.py", line 287, in __init__
        self.finalize_options()
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/setuptools/dist.py", line 258, in finalize_options
        ep.load()(self, ep.name, value)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/cffi/setuptools_ext.py", line 161, in cffi_modules
        add_cffi_module(dist, cffi_module)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/cffi/setuptools_ext.py", line 48, in add_cffi_module
        execfile(build_file_name, mod_vars)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/cffi/setuptools_ext.py", line 24, in execfile
        exec(code, glob, glob)
      File "src/build_bcrypt.py", line 29, in <module>
        """
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/cffi/api.py", line 105, in cdef
        self._cdef(csource, override=override, packed=packed)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/cffi/api.py", line 119, in _cdef
        self._parser.parse(csource, override=override, **options)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/cffi/cparser.py", line 290, in parse
        self._internal_parse(csource)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/cffi/cparser.py", line 295, in _internal_parse
        ast, macros, csource = self._parse(csource)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/cffi/cparser.py", line 230, in _parse
        csource, macros = _preprocess(csource)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/cffi/cparser.py", line 138, in _preprocess
        if pycparser.__version__ < '2.14':
    AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute '__version__'

    ----------------------------------------
Command "/usr/bin/python -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-UQAoWx/bcrypt/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-BL_G1e-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-UQAoWx/bcrypt
```

Tried:

```
sudo apt-get remove build-essential libffi-dev python-dev
sudo apt-get install build-essential libffi-dev python-dev
```

also tried:

```
sudo apt-get remove python-pycparser
sudo apt-get install python-pycparser
```

Comment: Have you read /tmp/pip-build-UQAoWx/bcrypt?

Comment: There is nothing there after installation

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I encountered similar problems when attempting

```
pip install --user --upgrade bcrypt
```

I had debian python-cffi package installed, version 0.8.6. After removing it the command above succeeded. The old version somehow caused problems even though new version of `cffi` had been installed using pip.

Also

```
pip uninstall  bcrypt cffi pycparser
pip install --user --upgrade cffi
pip install --user --upgrade bcrypt
```

seems to work even when python-cffi package is installed.

Comment: I still got an error, until I did "sudo apt-get install python3-dev"

Comment: This worked with python version 3.8.13. Windows Machine. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

[ensure that the required dependencies are installed](https://pypi.org/project/bcrypt/#:%7E:text=ensure%20that%20the%20required%20dependencies%20are%20installed) from the Homepage of bcrypt

```
apt-get install build-essential libffi-dev python-dev python3-dev
```